# NSMutableArray insertObject at the index = 0 creating null pointers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a NSMutable array which i am storing some initial numbers. What I want to do is to be able to look at the numbers, and for some situations, remove that item and replace it with two more.

My insert/replace code seems to work when index > 0, however, when I try to insertObject AtIndex:0, it doesnt insert anything at 0, but places a null object at the end of the array.

To show the insert issue I can create an empty iOS Application.

I create the NSMutableArray as a property on the ViewController:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *testArray;
```

And then in the implementation:

```
self.testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.testArray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]];
[self.testArray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2]];

[self.testArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:3] atIndex:0];
```

If i place a break point after the insert, the debugger shows:
    [0] = (id) 0x07123180 (int) 1
    [1] = (id) 0x07614210 (int) 2
    [2] = (id) 0x00000000

Where I was expecting to see an (int) 3 at place 0.

If I set atIndex:1, I get this:
    [0] = (id) 0x07123180 (int) 1
    [1] = (id) 0x07131fb0 (int) 3
    [2] = (id) 0x07614210 (int) 2

Which is correct.

Why is index = 0 not working?

Comment: Don't trust the debugger variables view! Print the object in the debugger console: `po self.testArray` or NSLog it in your code.

Comment: As an aside, you can use number literals: `[self.testArray addObject:@1];`, and `[self.testArray insertObject:@3 atIndex:0];` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [testArray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]];
        [testArray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2]];
        [testArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:3] atIndex:0];

        for (NSNumber *num in testArray)
            NSLog(@"%@", num);

    }
    return 0;
}

2013-09-15 09:51:18.266 ArrayTest[890:303] 3
2013-09-15 09:51:18.269 ArrayTest[890:303] 1
2013-09-15 09:51:18.269 ArrayTest[890:303] 2
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

If I break on the `for` statement and use lldb:

```
(lldb) po testArray
<__NSArrayM 0x100109120>(
3,
1,
2
)
```

(this was using Xcode 5 DP 6 under Mavericks DP 7).

Comment: Thank you for that - once I started outputting it to the console it seemed to work. However Im still confused why the debug output when doing a breakpoint isnt showing correctly - I tried this on my full code and the console outputted 1,1,2,4,8,16 while the breakpoint has 2,4,8,16 and two null objects. Strange! :)

Comment: @Michaeljhoward it's possibly a buggy `lldb`. What version are you using?

Comment: XCode 4.6.3 - the latest official patch before iOS 7 betas.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
 testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 [testArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
 [testArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];

 [testArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] atIndex:0];

 NSLog(@"%@",testArray);
```

Log

2013-09-15 10:53:39.048 JsonExample[79141:a0b] (
    0,
    1,
    2
)

I copied your sample code too and it works fine in Xcode 4